# jQuery get label from above

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a function to update an order receipt every time the user updates and then closes  a product pop-up overlay. 
The function searches each input of the form, and then adds the info to the receipt div if its value is greater than `0`. I am trying to get the `.html()` of the label element situated above the input field and which describes the current item, and to use this as the description of the item in the receipt.

I have tried using without success:

```
 - $this.closest('label').html() 
 - $this.prev('label').html()
 - $this.find('label').html()
 - this.element.find('label').html()
```

Here is my code. The section I am talking about is the 'label is' part...

```
function updateOrder(){

var items = '';
$('input').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        i_value = $this.attr('value');

    if(i_value > 0){
      items += $this.attr('id') + ' Quantity: ' + i_value + '<br/>' 
      + 'label is: ' + $this.closest('label').html() + '<br/>';  
    }
});

$('#d_reciept').html(items);
```

}

and a sample form item

```
<tr>
<td class="td_thumbs">
    <div>
        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="vinyl-banners" href="img/products/vinyl-corporateblue.jpg"> <img src="img/products/thumbs/vinyl-corporateblue-thumb.png" alt="vinyl c-blue"/></a>
        <label>Corporate Blue</label>
    </div>
</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>
    <input id="vinyl-blue" type="number" max="6" min="0" value="0"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function `closest` give you first accurance of given selector in `ancestors`, your label is not in the first ancestors, rather in the parent tr `children`, You need to go to parent tr and then use find to search its parent for `label`.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('label').html()
```

or

```
$(this).closest('tr :td:eq(0)').find('label').html()
```

Comment: brilliant! $(this).closest('tr').find('label').html() worked :)